# Blazor WASM - Azure AD B2C authentication and img sources

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly

I do authentication in my Blazor WASM app using Azure AD B2C and I can call my protected REST api without problems. The issues I run into now is for image sources and these protected endpoints. Eg

`<img src='/myapi/projects/{GUID}/picture' />`

now gives me a 401 result and the images not showing because the JWT bearer header is missing.

Is there a way to enable cookie authentication for image sources or is there some way to intercept the call and add the JWT bearer header to the image source or any other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: How are you protecting these endpoints?

Comment: JWT bearer access tokens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated the different solutions proposed by the following blog

[Web Security: Images behind Auth](https://gaurav5430.medium.com/web-security-images-behind-auth-bb0b955c4770)

And in the end I went for generating the signed img urls in the WASM client based on a container SAS I received through my REST api. The possible dmg that somebody could do by intercepting the SAS token is limited, because its a read-only container SAS that expires after an hour.